# blueimp jQuery-File-Upload : store file outside webroot

Tags: jquery, file, upload

I don't use to upload image, but all possible files.
Is it possible to store files outside the webroot ? (PHP)

Thanks
Hugh

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry, I see now. It already can work with outside webroot folder.

```
    $upload_handler = new UploadHandler(array(
      "upload_dir" => '/host/app/files',
      "download_via_php" => 1,
    )) ;
```

:)